# How can I add Spring Security OAuth tokens to Crnk Client?

Tags: java, spring, oauth-2.0, spring-security-oauth2, crnk

I want to use Crnk Client 3.4 to consume a JSON:API endpoint that is secured with OAuth2. I am using a `client_credentials` grant and Spring Security OAuth2 (with Boot) to configure the credentials.

Since the Spring team has decided to try to force everyone onto reactive WebClient, there is no out-of-the-box RestTemplate interceptor that can retrieve an access token from Spring Security OAuth2, which suggests that I'll have to do some level of integration on my own.

Is there a best practice for supplying an access token to a `CrnkClient` instance? [The documentation mentions `SecurityModule` in passing](http://www.crnk.io/releases/stable/documentation/#_modules), but it doesn't seem that it actually supports adding credentials. I could write a module, but it appears that to add headers I want to implement `HttpAdapterListener`, and modules don't provide a mechanism to register them; instead they have `HttpRequestProcessor`, which is not used at all by the client.

I can see two possible clean integration options; is either of these recommended or discouraged?

1. Write the missing `ClientHttpRequestInterceptor` to integrate Spring Security OAuth2. Create a `RestTemplate` in a bean method using `RestTemplateBuilder` and add the OAuth2 interceptor. Call `crnkClient.setHttpAdapter(new RestTemplateAdapter(interceptedRt))`.
2. Write a Crnk `Module` implementing `HttpAdapterAware` that is a Spring bean and contributes an `HttpAdapterListener` that retrieves the access token and calls `HttpAdapterRequest#header`.

Comment: something new about this question?